# No puedo llegar a otro servidor para consumir un método específico de un web service

Tags: .net, webservice, pdf

Estoy trabajando en un equipo dentro de una red `192.168.0.XXX` y estoy consumiendo un Web Service alojado en un servidor `190.153.227.XXX`.

El problema está en que en el Web Service (ubicado en `190.153.227.XXX`) consumo 3 métodos, de los cuales 2 inyectan y actualizan datos sin ningún problema en la base de datos del otro servidor pero el 3er método en que envío unos datos y me retorna un pdf en binario no consigo llegar a efectuar el consumo.

Ya hablé con el administrador de red por temas de permiso, revisamos firewall, probé el consumo de los web service en mi equipo y no da problemas.

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> "No se puede ir automáticamente al servidor. Error de conexión con el servidor 'certificación.dimfactor.cl' *(que corresponde al 190.153.227.XXX:80)*. El depurador no se puede conectar con el equipo remoto. Puede que no exista tal equipo o que un firewall impida la comunicación con éste. Vea la ayuda para obtener mas información"

Como dato adicional esto ya se hizo para otro cliente y funcionó sin problemas. Probé las fuentes del otro cliente y ya no funciona el consumo en desarrollo así que se me vino a la mente que hicieron alguna modificación pero si eso fuera así no podría consumir los 2 primeros métodos.

También revise la referencia Web, el nombre del método por si estaba mal escrito, el tag de los parámetros (lo cual no debiera ser un problema porque en ese caso llegaria al otro servidor pero este no recibiria los datos).

Comment: Revisa el certificado, puede que haya expirado y/o no exista, pero se reporta un error diferente.

Comment: Hola. Has comprobado si tienes conectividad con ese servidor tanto por IP como por nombre? Tao vez te falte agregar una entrada al archivo hosts ubicado en C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Answer (score 0):

La dirección IP que indicas es una dirección IP de un operador de telecomunicaciones de chile. Debes comprobar que el tráfico entre ambos equipos es posible siempre, además de realizarlo (a poder ser) sobre un protocolo SSL mínimo, para evitar interceptar los datos y no sobre el 80.

Compara la ruta y el destino desde el equipo que comentas que funciona en otro cliente con el tuyo, utiliza la dirección IP en lugar del nombre completo DNS para verificar que no existen problemas de resolución locales.

Por otro lado, el error que muestras indica que no puede conectar tu debugger (depuración remota) de tu equipo con el servicio remoto. 
Si el servicio lo ejecutaras en local dentro de tu solución deberías comprobar antivirus/firewall de terceros, la comunicación de Visual Studio localmente. 
En el caso de un servicio externo de WS añade a tu solución la referencia de nuevo para comprobar que no ha habido variaciones en las llamadas del tercer método en discordia, un cambio no reflejado en tus clases mapeadas al webservice.

Si todo esto sigue sin resolver los problemas de comunicación entre ambas partes, utiliza "**Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger**" (gratuito) u otro servidor proxy intermedio para ver más claramente las comunicaciones entre ambos extremos.

Answer (score -1):

Si te funcionan dos métodos pero el tercero no, entonces puede ser un problema de configuración.

Si estás usando *SSL* entonces revisa tu **web.config**. Ve a la etiqueta `serviceMetadata` y revisa que la bandera `httpGetEnabled` esté como `httpsGetEnabled` y en estado verdadero.

Pero insisto, si el servicio responde, además puedes usar dos métodos, entonces es problema de configuración. Habilita *DEBUG* y revisa dónde se se cae.

Adjunto fuente:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/fc2b468b-1e76-45fd-b4a2-2aa2df1498bc/error-al-crear-una-referencia-de-servicio?forum=vcses